# is it possible to Integrate ckeditor5 using GWT

Tags: ckeditor5

Hi [ckeditor5](/questions/tagged/ckeditor5) Experts,

I have started exploring the possibilities to integrate the ckeditor 5 in my GWT application.
Can someone help me to understand what will be required to integrate it.

I am new to GWT so don't have enough idea about it.
Ckeditor 5 plugins are written in typescript, is it psossible to use typescript in GWT ?

Thanks

I tried to explore the exiting GWT-ckeditor get repo but it is not active and support ended at ckeditor4.
As ckeditor 5 is completely different than ckeditor 4 and support typescript, I just need some pointers on how to proceed ?